# queue.empty and doing a put while empty

Tags: python, queue

Let's say I have a queue of two elements.
I loop though the queue popping off the items using get. I'm afraid the loop will stop looping once I pop off the second element, and I need to reprocess it because of some error. So I put it back in the queue, but it won't since by then the queue is empty.

My loop:

```
while not queue.empty():
    try:
        item = queue.get()
        do stuff(item):
    except Exception as e:
        queue.put(item)
    queue.task_done()
```

I read the documentation on [`Queue.empty()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.empty) but getting confused about blocking and what it means.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with multiple threads as it looks like to me (why else would you be concerned about blocking?), it is in general not a good idea to do this:

```
if not queue.empty():  # or 'while' instead of 'if'
    item = queue.get()
```

because another thread could have emptied your `queue` between the first and the second line, so your `queue.get()` now blocks until anything new comes in, which seems not to be expected behavior if you wrote that. Basically the `if not queue.empty()` is meaningless in a concurrency kind of scenario.

The right way to do this would rather be:

```
try:
    while True:
        item = queue.get(block=False)
        done = False
        while not done:
            try:
                do stuff(item)
                done = True
            except Exception as e:
                pass  # just try again to do stuff
        queue.task_done()
except Empty:
    pass  # no more items
```

*Other than that* (if we assume, no other thread can consume your queue), the code would work fine. I have some serious doubts though about whether you understand (or 'understood', since the question is old) the concept of blocking.
 If a function is 'blocking' according to the documentation, that just means that the execution of your code will be halted at that point until some event occurs. `time.sleep(1)` is maybe the best example of a blocking function that blocks for 1 second.

PS: I know this is some years old, but still...