# Basic multiprocessing with infinity loop and queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import random
import queue as Queue
import _thread as Thread

a = Queue.Queue()

def af():
    while True:
        a.put(random.randint(0,1000))

def bf():
    while True:
        if (not a.empty()): print (a.get())

def main():
    Thread.start_new_thread(af, ())
    Thread.start_new_thread(bf, ())
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the above code works fine with extreme high CPU usage, i tried to use multiprocessing with no avail. i have tried

```
def main():
    multiprocessing.Process(target=af).run()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=bf).run()
```

and

```
def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    a = manager.Queue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.apply_async(af)
    pool.apply_async(bf)
```

both not working, can anyone please help me? thanks a bunch ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first alternative `main` you use `Process`, but the method you should call to start the activity is **not** `run()`, as one would think, but rather `start()`. You will want to follow that up with appropriate `join()` statements. Following the information in `multiprocessing` (available here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), here is a working sample:

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def af(q):
    while True:
        q.put(random.randint(0,1000))

def bf(q):
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            print (q.get())

def main():
    a = Queue()  
    p = Process(target=af, args=(a,))
    c = Process(target=bf, args=(a,))
    p.start()
    c.start()
    p.join()
    c.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thank u very much for the answer, however i dont see a decrease in CPU usage against the thread method, anything i done wrong?

Comment: I think that's expected. Having a `while true` loop that mostly computes a random number, is bound to be CPU intensive. You could throttle that in few ways, one being to put `sleep` statements in *both* functions `af` and `bf` (say for 2 seconds) and see if that reduces the CPU usage to your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    multiprocessing.Process(target=af).run()  # will not return
    multiprocessing.Process(target=bf).run()
```

The above code does not work because `af` does not return; no chance to call `bf`. You need to separate `run` call to `start`/`join` so that both can run in parallel. (+ to make them share `manage.Queue`)

---

To make the second code work, you need to pass `a` (`manager.Queue` object) to functions. Otherwise they will use `Queue.Queue` global object which is not shared between processes; need to modify `af`, `bf` to accepts `a`, and `main` to pass `a`.

```
def af(a):
    while True:
        a.put(random.randint(0, 1000))

def bf(a):
    while True:
        print(a.get())
def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    a = manager.Queue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    proc1 = pool.apply_async(af, [a])
    proc2 = pool.apply_async(bf, [a])

    # Wait until process ends. Uncomment following line if there's no waiting code.
    # proc1.get()
    # proc2.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560649/12492588), in the original code:

```
while True:
    if not q.empty():
        print (q.get())
```

`q.empty()` is being called every time which is unnecessary since `q.get()` if the queue is empty will wait until something is available [here documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get).

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53804080/12492588)

I assume that this could affect the performance since calling the .empty() every iteration should consume more resources (it should be more noticeable if Thread was used instead of Process because Python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL))

I know it's an old question but hope it helps!